# Two popups open when sharing tweet?

Tags: javascript, html, api, twitter, popup

I'm using a button that will let visitors tweet the blog post. I'm using the following code:

```
<li class="ft-stwitter">
      <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.mywebebsite.com/the-url/&amp;text=Blog Title" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
      '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
        <i class="icon-twitter"></i> Share on Twitter
      </a>
  </li>
```

It works fine.
On the same page, I've the official Twitter follow button too. The code is as follows:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/cracked" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name='false' data-lang="en">Follow @Storypicker</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Now when I click on "Share on Twitter" link, two popups open. How can I fix it? What am I doing wrong? Please guide me. :(

Here's the problem fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zk79C/2/

**UPDATE:**

The issue was a bug but it is marked as fixed. https://dev.twitter.com/issues/191

Comment: You are using both an `href` and doing `window.open` in an `onclick` handler. Hence the code obliges and opens 2 windows for you. Stick to any one of them.

Comment: If you have a problem with client side code, then show people the client side code - not some PHP that generates it. It is also helpful to make use of new lines and indentation instead of stuffing the whole thing on two lines.

Comment: @srvikram13 — There's a return false in there.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry I missed that. @LittleLebowski Can you try removing `target="_blank"`?

Comment: Sorry, let me add the client side code too. And sorry for the bad copy paste of code without indentation.

Comment: @srvikram13, removing target="_blank" didn't work. Problem persists.

Comment: Question edited with client side rendered code.

Comment: @LittleLebowski It's working fine for me in all major browsers! [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/zk79C/show/) (Opens just a single window)

Comment: Strangely, this is working for me too. I'm using Wordpress. What might cause this problem then? Confused.

Comment: @srvikram13, I've updated the question with a fiddle.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I solved it myself.
Here's the solution:

```
<li class="ft-stwitter">
      <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.mywebebsite.com/the-url/&amp;text=Blog Title">
        <i class="icon-twitter"></i> Share on Twitter
      </a>
  </li>
```

The onclick is not required.

Comment: Yep, need to wait 20 more hours to do so. Anyway, thanks for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

In the href, replace

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?

by

https://twitter.com/share?

this solved the issue for me. It seems that the first url is calling a script which opens the second popup. But, oddly, this happens only in Firefox (current v51.0.1).

[source](https://github.com/kni-labs/rrssb/issues/181)

Comment: had the same problem with firefox 56 and this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your link opens a new window and then the javascript does too.

Show the HTML that appears in the browser and not your server code

Comment: No. The JavaScript will run first. The JavaScript also ends in `return false` which should prevent the default behaviour of the link.

Comment: I've edited the question to add the HTML that appears in the browser.

Comment: Yes working in all latest browsers for me too. Strange

Comment: Edited the question. I've found the root of the problem. Not the solution. Please check.